# Is there a way to query ltrees in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Is there any sort of extension that would allow me to use Postgres ltrees in JOOQ without having to use raw SQL?

Any way to make one myself maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Starting from jOOQ 3.17:

With [#13188](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13188), jOOQ has added native support for `LTREE` types (and similar) via the `jooq-postgres-extensions` module:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-postgres-extensions</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Just add that module to both code generation and runtime classpaths, and the code generator will auto-configure the relevant `Binding` for you.

#### Before jOOQ 3.17:

You have to implement a custom data type binding ([`org.jooq.Binding`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Binding.html)) and apply that to your generated code: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings.

A `Binding` allows you to tell jOOQ how to:

- generate SQL for it (probably something like `?::ltree` in your case)
- bind your data type to JDBC

  - `PreparedStatement`
  - `SQLOutput` (optional, when your type is contained in a UDT, currently only in Oracle)
- read it from JDBC

  - `ResultSet`
  - `CallableStatement` (optional, when you fetch it from a function `OUT` parameter)
  - `SQLInput` (optional, when your type is contained in a UDT, currently only in Oracle)